# Username - Password program in c

Tags: c, passwords

I have an assignment for my degree and this is the exercise:
Write a program in c that asks the user for the username and his password(up to 10 digits).
Every time the user presses a key while writing the password, put a '*' in its place without letting the real password being seen.
Then print the username, the password and the lenght of the password.
This is my code that I think should run properly but does nothing at all. Can you give me some help with it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

main()
{
    int i=0;
    char a[10];
loop1:
    while(a[i]!='\r'){
        for(i;i<=10;i++){
            a[i] = getch();
            goto loop1;
        }
        puts('*');
    }
    for(i=0;i<=10;i++){
        printf("%c",a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for every comment and answer you provide!

Comment: Follow the logic here. Your program will run until it reaches "getch()" and then it blocks, waiting for keyboard input. When it gets this input, it will write it into a[0] and then it will jump OUT of the while-loop and repeat this process. Your program will forever write the keyboard input into a[0] and never proceed past this loop.

Comment: To answer we need to know what operating system you are using. This can't be done using only standard C; it's possible with extensions but they are all different.

Comment: Using `goto` and labels for any kind of loop-handling is highly discouraged almost universally. It tend to lead to *spaghetti code* which is hard to follow and understand.

Comment: @zwol conio.h means windows.

Comment: @siride Well it could mean DOS as well, as that's where the header file originated from. ;)

Comment: It's not the answer to your question, but i=0 to i=10 is 11 characters.

Comment: @siride In context, the presence of `#include <conio.h>` could just mean OP copied some Windows-specific boilerplate without understanding it.